# unable to remove images in canvas : javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am new to javascript. I am  creating new images in my js file by saying 
What I intend to is draw a new image and remove the previous one...

My code sample is :

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = 'abc.png';

ctx.drawImage(image, x, y,30,30);
```

and then I am using

```
ctx.clearRect(x, y, 30, 30);
```

but it does not clear the images drawn..
What should I do?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Worksforme. Could you add some code (e.g. what happens to `x` and `y` meanwhile) or build a demo?

Comment: For me it works also. http://jsfiddle.net/QXLM4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this  [HTML5 canvas tutorial for clear and redraw new image](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-images/)

Hope this can be helpful for you.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="400"></canvas>
    <script>
      var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      var imageObj = new Image();

      imageObj.onload = function() {
        context.drawImage(imageObj, 69, 50);
      };
      imageObj.src = 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg';
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```